# Applying a for loop to a list

Tags: r

I am trying to compute the gdp value of several countries of a period t from the value at t-1 and the growth rate. For this I created this for loop which works well when applied to a single country:

```
growth_function = function(x, value, growth){
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    value[i] <- (value[[i-1]])*(1+growth[[i]])
  }
}
```

To apply it to all countries, I used split() on my dataframe and created a list with all countries. Then I wanted to do as follow:

```
projections_list <- lapply(projections_list, growth_function('iso', 'mnninc', 'gdp_growth'))
```

But i have the following message error:

```
Error in growth[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

You can find an element of my list in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es0Jr.png). All elements are constructed the same.
If anyone could give a hint to find a solution, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you paste the result of `dput(projections_list[[1]])` and `dput(projections_list[[2]])` into the original post

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `x[[value]]` and `x[[growth]]` in your function, when trying to access columns of `x` using strings `value` and `growth`.

Perhaps re-write your function like this:

```
growth_function = function(x, value, growth){
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    x[[value]][i] <- (x[[value]][[i-1]])*(1+x[[growth]][[i]])
  }
  return(x[[value]])
}
```

and call this function on each element of `projections_list` like this:

```
lapply(projections_list, \(i) growth_function(i, value="mnnic", growth = "gdp_growth"))
```

Please note that because you are looping from `2:length(x)` in the function, and assigning to `x[[value]][i]`, the last element of `x[[value]]` will be `NA`. Finally, I assume you understand that this will not change the actual value of the `mnnic` column within each of the dataframes in `projections_list`.